# Did Narcissus have a twin sister?

Tags: greek

It's been over twenty years when I was reading about the story of Narcissus.  I don't have any of my notes or references saved, but I distinctly remembered I read one or two stories mentioning Narcissus had a twin sister.  Can anyone tell me if this is true and if there is literature on this?

Comment: If I answered your question as noted by you below my answer, would you be so kind to accept my answer?

Answer (score 7):

The ancient Greek writer and geographer [Pausanias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pausanias_(geographer)) recorded a variant of the well know story of [Narcissus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology)) falling in love with himself, in which Narcissus falls in love with his twin sister rather than himself.

> [9.31.8] There is another story about Narcissus, less popular indeed than the other, but not without some support. It is said that Narcissus had a twin sister; they were exactly alike in appearance, their hair was the same, they wore similar clothes, and went hunting together. The story goes on that Narcissus fell in love with his sister, and when the girl died, would go to the spring, knowing that it was his reflection that he saw, but in spite of this knowledge finding some relief for his love in imagining that he saw, not his own reflection, but the likeness of his sister.<sub>[Guide to Greece, 9.31.8](https://www.theoi.com/Text/Pausanias9B.html)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much!  I believe this was it.